# Toggle html button depending if textarea is filled or empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hey the task i try to achieve is to activate and deactivate a button depending on, if there is text in a textarea or not.

Here the code I'm trying to get going.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button_01");
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea_01");

$(button).prop('disabled', true);

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  button.disabled = !this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_01">
  <h1>String Editor</h1>
  <textarea id="textarea_01" rows="5" placeholder="Paste your string here"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="div_02">
  <h1>Options</h1>
  <button id="button_01" type="button" value="submit">
      Modify
      </button>
</div>
```

and here a fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amsrq1tc/)

- What I'm really not understanding here is, why the button which I disabled in the js part is still active

I'm an absolute html/js/web developement newbie, so please give some explanation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your JSFiddle isn't working because you did not include jQuery CDN link.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?  Like a big red `$ is not defined`  https://jsfiddle.net/z02gsxt9/   Always check the console.

Comment: Based on @0stone0 's observation, I've converted your code to a snippet in the question and it appears to work fine.  Please update to demonstrate the issue, otherwise looks like just missing jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsFiddle doesn't work because there's no jQuery CDN link.

<sup>You can find an updated version, witch includes the jQuery CDN [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sry5a78o/)</sup>.

---

You're using jQuery to disable the button on page-load.

I'll recommend using HTML for that:

```html
<button id="button_01" type="button" value="submit" disabled>
```

Then, your code appears to work just fine because there's no jQuery needed anymore:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button_01");
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea_01");

textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    button.disabled = !this.value;
});
```

```html
<div id="div_01">
  <h1>String Editor</h1>
  <textarea id="textarea_01" rows="5" placeholder="Paste your string here"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="div_02">
  <h1>Options</h1>
  <button id="button_01" type="button" value="submit" disabled>
  Modify
  </button>
</div>
```

**Note**;

1. Changed event from `keyup` to `input` so things like right-click and paste will trigger the event. (Thx to [@freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67304158/toggle-html-button-depending-if-textarea-is-filled-or-empty/67304201#comment118964454_67304201))

Comment: You might like to consider using `input` event rather than keyup - as there's more than one way to get values into the box (eg right-click paste)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
   var button = document.getElementById("button_01");
   var  textarea =  document.getElementById("textarea_01");

   button.disabled = true;

   textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
       button.disabled = !this.value;
   });
```

```html
       <div id="div_01">
          <h1>String Editor</h1>
          <textarea id="textarea_01" rows="5" placeholder="Paste your string here"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <div id="div_02">
          <h1>Options</h1>
          <button id="button_01" type="button" value="submit">
          Modify
          </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your question. 'Try like this' isn't that helpful since OP would have to 'search' for the fix. Please take a look at: [answer].